# How should I learn to play Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am interested in learning how to play Dwarf Fortress. Where should I start, as an absolute beginner?

Comment: What version are you playing? The community hasn't really picked up on the 2010 edition afaik.

Comment: I started playing last week, for the first time, with the 2010 version, and I don't think I've had any issues with documentation.

Comment: @badp I agree with antony, the [wiki](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/Main_Page) and this site are obviously very up to date on DF2010.

Comment: @antony.trupe Of course you haven't had any trouble with the documentation... you didn't read any of it. :) You just ask questions on here. I hope your fortress gets infested by madness.

Comment: @I Never Finish Anythi madness would be great Fun. How do I get infested by madness?

Comment: @C. Ross, [The quickstart guide](http://df.magmawiki.com/index.php/DF2010:Quickstart_guide) and its savefile are not updated for DF2010 :/

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4314/what-is-dwarf-fortress

Comment: @antony.trupe - Just playing Dwarf Fortress is all that is necessary.

Comment: I would say "Try and die", you can only get better by losing ;D

Comment: I hate to be a spoil sport, but this question is not only opinionated and thereby technically impossible to correctly answer, but you never accepted any answer either.

Answer (score 25):

I like [this set of tutorials](http://afteractionreporter.com/dwarf-fortress-tutorials/). It's based on the old version but it goes through the steps of building a fortress pretty well.

Answer (score 19):

Captain Duck has a great series of video tutorials (http://www.youtube.com/user/captnduck). Most of them are for pre-2010 versions, but they still give a great intro to the game, and he has started to make a couple of videos for the 2010 version. He starts the tutorials at the absolute beginning, and walks you through everything.

If you have any specific questions, the dwarf fortress wiki is a great place to look (https://dwarffortresswiki.org/).

Comment: I came here to post pretty much this. +1 Sir.

Comment: The youtube videos have been updated to the Feb 2012 version of dwarf fortress

Answer (score 8):

Different styles work better for different people, but I learned the [fun](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Fun) way:

1. Begin
2. Lose
3. Figure out what happened
4. Repeat

If you're stuck on something specific, there's nothing wrong with looking at a tutorial or checking the [wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Main_Page), but try not to over-research before you really get your feet wet. One of the coolest things about learning to play DF is discovering all of the neat/interesting/strange/complex things that the world does and researching too much before hand will diminish the sense of discovery.

Answer (score 6):

Learn how to feed and hydrate your dwarfs.

Specifically, learn how to [farm](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Farm): [mill](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Milling) plants into [flour](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Flour) with a [quern](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Quern) and [cook](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Cooking) that flour into  meals at a [kitchen](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Kitchen), and [brew](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Brewer) [alcohol](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Alcohol) at a [still](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Still).

There's a [Quickstart guide](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Quickstart_guide) at [The Dwarf Fortress Wiki](https://dwarffortresswiki.org), which is an invaluble reference site. I didn't have any issues applying the previous version's tutorial(v0.28.181.40d) to the current version(v0.31.10).

Comment: That's reasonable to start, but there's so much more a DF player has to learn; i don't recommend that unless headbanging is a desired activity.

Comment: @RCIX headbanging is the bread and butter of a DF player.

Comment: many links are broken

Answer (score 5):

[Getting Started with Dwarf Fortress](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022565.do) is a book that's been recently released and is a great way to learn to play.

It's by Peter Tyson, the same guy who wrote the [The Complete and Utter Newbie Tutorial for Dwarf Fortress](http://afteractionreporter.com/2009/02/09/the-complete-and-utter-newby-tutorial-for-dwarf-fortress-part-1-wtf/).

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the #DwarfFortress channel on quakenet. If you do not know how to use IRC you can plug that channel into http://webchat.quakenet.org and get on. There is usually tons of people around, just be patient as they might not instantly answer