# The Easiest Setup for a new Dwarf Fortress Player

Tags: dwarf-fortress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I learn to play Dwarf Fortress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-should-i-learn-to-play-dwarf-fortress)

I am having some trouble breaking in to Dwarf Fortress.

I booted up the game for the first time and there were soooo many options for my new game.  And when I started playing, it appeared like the game would play itself for hours and hours and I hardly had to lift a finger.

What is a good initial setup for a player that wants to learn the game?  Do I want to start with a big world with very few beasts?  A small world with lots of minerals? What is the best initial combo?

(My goal here is just to learn, I am not interested in the long-term viability of my world.)

Comment: See also: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-should-i-learn-to-play-dwarf-fortress

Comment: Blood for the Blood God!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first few times I played, I followed the quickstart guide from the Dwarf Fortress wiki, located [here](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Quickstart_guide). It's extremely helpful, and walks you through the UI, controls, and world generation, as well as getting a fortress started.

There is also an e-book: [Getting Started with Dwarf Fortress](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022565.do). There was a coupon code for 40% off, but I can't remember what it was, and I'm not sure if it's still active. If I find it, I'll add it here.

Comment: use TIM40 for 40%

Comment: @mxmissile - Ah, thanks, I hadn't been able to find it again.

Answer (score 7):

You'll probably want to install the [lazy newb pack](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/Lazy_Newb_Pack), and then start following this [quick start guide](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Quickstart_guide) to the letter. It includes these topics, among many others:

- World Generation
- Pre-Embark

  - Choosing a Good Site
  - Skills and Equipment
- A Minimal Fortress

Comment: I did this and recommend it. Read the wiki, keep it open as you play.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not playing on Windows, so I cannot use this game extension.

Comment: @theJollySin - Ah, that's how I started out playing DF, on my Linux install, so I've never gotten in to using the lazy newb pack. I'd definitely recommend installing a tileset, it makes the game much more enjoyable. If you're on Ubuntu, there is a early beta version of Dwarf Therapist built for it [here](http://code.google.com/p/dwarftherapist/wiki/LinuxVersion). Dwarf Therapist is extremely helpful. I didn't start using it til recently, and it makes the game so much more fun. Besides that, the book and guide still work on other OS's :)

Comment: @SaintWacko Yup, I'm on Ubuntu.  I will try Dwarf Therapist tonight. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you watch [Captnduck's videos](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL06686270DA5FF439&feature=plcp).